# trying to loop HTML buttons using PHP and added an EventListener in JS using querySelector but only first iterated buttons are getting selected

Tags: javascript, php

i am looping HTML buttons using PHP and adding EventListener  for those buttons in JS using querySelector but only the first set of buttons are getting selected

Need to try querySelectorAll  or please suggest something to make it work
[screenshot]

```
<?php  $query='SELECT * FROM `posts`';

     $result= mysqli_query( $conn,$query);
            if(!$result){
                echo "query1 failed";
            }
    while($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo $rows['post_text'];


          ?>
            <br>
    <form method="post" action="index.php" id="form">

         <button   type="submit" name="like" id='like' class="button" >   <i class="ion-ios-thumbs-up like icon"></i>  </button> 
        <button type="submit" name="love"  id='heart' ><i class="ion-ios-heart icon heart icon"></i></button>
       <button type="submit" name="dislike" id='dislike' ><i class="ion-ios-thumbs-down dislike icon"></i></button>
    </form>
            <br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>


         <script>

           document.querySelector('.like').addEventListener('click', function fn(e) {
                e.preventDefault();


                   document.querySelector('.like').style.color='#3483e6';
                document.querySelector('.dislike').style.color='#555';
               document.querySelector('.heart').style.color='#555';



            });</script>
```

I want all the buttons under all post should behave like first set of buttons

Comment: `querySelector` only returns the first element from the matched set to begin with. You want `querySelectorAll` - but you still need to _loop over_ the collection of elements that returns, and assign the handler for each item individually.

Comment: And IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, so what you are creating in a loop here results in invalid HTML to begin with. Go fix that first of all.

Comment: how i can loop over using queryselectorAll

Comment: Can i use as below 


 var abc= document.querySelector('.like');

   
 abc.forEach(

 addEventListener('click', function fn(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
      
    
      document.querySelector('.like').style.color='#3483e6';
      document.querySelector('.dislike').style.color='#555';
     document.querySelector('.heart').style.color='#555';
   
                
       
        });
 
 );

Comment: No, `document.querySelector('.like').style.color=…` is going to present the same problem again - that will set the style for the _first_ `.like` element in the document only. You need to limit this selection to the current “context” - like from the currently clicked element (`this` inside your handler function), go up to the `form` parent node, and then select the element with class `like` inside of that …

Answer (score 0):

[Check Official Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Return_value) The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.